# Building Nhibernate Clauses With Custom Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

i've been trying to create an Expression to put on my where clause.

Since i can't directly return an Func (since nhibernate can't use it to convert into sql) i'm trying to return an Expression>

To do it, i've tried to go into a deeper level... using Expressions directly

But.. i've been searching around without any solution... Can anyone help me ?

Here's the code:

```
private static void Teste()
{
    var repo = new Repository<ViewRelatorioOrdemServico>(MockDevDatabase.CurrentSession()).Queryable();
    var filtro = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
    repo = repo.Where(FilterDateDe(x => x.DataCriacao.Value, filtro));
    foreach (var item in repo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.NumeroOS);
    }
}

public static Expression<Func<ViewRelatorioOrdemServico, bool>> FilterDateDe(Expression<Func<ViewRelatorioOrdemServico, DateTime>> exp, DateTime dataDe)
{
    var right = Expression.Constant(dataDe, typeof(DateTime));            
    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(exp, right);
}
```

My question is... how to create my Expression>

I've been trying a LOT of different ways... found some frameworks to do it .. but i'm trying to avoid those... and implement my own solution to this.

These are for academic purposes

Comment: Why don't you just use the expression directly? I mean: `query.Where(x => x.DataCriacao.HasValue && x.DataCriacao.Value >= filtro);`. Or you need something dynamic?

Comment: I need it dynamic... i have some places that i have like ... 16 date filters... and i want to keep it clean. Btw, i've saw a LOT of places with your comments in similar topics.. haha.

Comment: Take a look at [`Expression.Lambda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. Something like `return Expression.Lambda<Func<ViewRelatorioOrdemServico, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(exp.Body, right), exp.Parameters);`

Comment: Dude, i LOVE you. i've been trying to figure out what to do and FINALLY it worked!!! Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for those who helped, Specially to Ivan !!!

The final answer is the following code:L

```
public static Expression<Func<ViewRelatorioOrdemServico, bool>> FilterDateDe(Expression<Func<ViewRelatorioOrdemServico, DateTime>> exp, DateTime dataDe)
{
    var right = Expression.Constant(dataDe, typeof(DateTime));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<ViewRelatorioOrdemServico, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(exp.Body, right), exp.Parameters);
}
```

After that, i can play with the syntax and make some advanced strongly typed filters!

Thanks!!